# Incompatible error with When statement in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-when

The Below code gives me the "Incompatible types:Boolean and Int". Not sure what might be the issue.

```
 var votersAge = 17
 var cardEligibility = when(votersAge)
    {
        (votersAge > 18) -> true
        (votersAge <= 18) -> false
        else -> false
    }
```

Comment: Read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of `when(votersAge)` as a expression that in this case evaluates to an `Int`. In when's body, the logic branches according to the value of the expression and so expects an `Int` , you however provide a Boolean.

`when` expression/statement is documented [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression)

Try this:

```
 val votersAge = 17
 val cardEligibility = when
    {
        votersAge > 18 -> true
        else -> false
    }
```

or alternatively, this:

```
    val cardEligibilityw = when (votersAge)
    {
        in 0..18 -> false
        else -> true
    }
```